# About To Re-Watch The Toy Story Franchise, What is the Best Order?

Tags: suggested-order, pixar, toy-story

So, the material listed is as follows:

- *Lightyear* (Upcoming film) - Meant to be the story of the real Buzz Lightyear that inspired the toy of the same name.
- *Toy Story*
- *Toy Story 2*
- *Toy Story 3*
- *Toy Story 4*
- *Buzz Lightyear of Star Command: The Adventure Begins*
- *Buzz Lightyear of Star Command: The Animated Series*
- *The Toy Story That Time Forgot*
- *Forky Asks A Question*
- *Lamp Life*
- *Toy Story Treats*
- *Toy Story Toons*
- *Toy Story of Terror!*

What is the best viewing order for all of this?

Comment: Release order (which is also chronological order I believe) makes the most sense in my opinion.

Answer (score 9):

The key elements of the canon are the four Toy Story movies. The additional tie-in materials *fit between* the various films but without altering or adding to the canon.

As such, the tie-ins can be watched (or not) as you see fit, without missing anything in the subsequent films, **but must be watched *after* their respective films in order to avoid introducing spoilers**. For example, [Zurg's big reveal](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=38W6G3Ud7ms) (in Toy Story 2) to Buzz is [mocked](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vdt2h37HJy4) in *Buzz Lightyear of Star Command*.

---

- [**Toy Story**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story_(franchise)#Toy_Story_(1995)) (1995)

  - [Toy Story Treats](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story_(franchise)#Toy_Story_Treats) (1996)
- [**Toy Story 2**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story_(franchise)#Toy_Story_2_(1999)) (1999)

  - [Buzz Lightyear of Star Command: The Adventure Begins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzz_Lightyear_of_Star_Command:_The_Adventure_Begins) (2000) (This 'TV-movie' acts as a pilot for the TV series)
  - [Buzz Lightyear of Star Command (Series)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzz_Lightyear_of_Star_Command) (2000)
- [**Toy Story 3**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story_(franchise)#Toy_Story_3_(2010)) (2010)

  - [Toy Story Toons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story_(franchise)#Toy_Story_Toons) (2011)
  - [Toy Story of Terror!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story_of_Terror!) (2013)
  - [Toy Story That Time Forgot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story_That_Time_Forgot) (2014)
- [**Toy Story 4**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story_(franchise)#Toy_Story_4_(2019)) (2019)

  - [Forky Asks a Question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story_(franchise)#Forky_Asks_a_Question) (2019)
  - [Lamp Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story_(franchise)#Lamp_Life) (2020)
- [**Lightyear***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toy_Story_(franchise)#Lightyear_(2022)) (2022)

---

*Note that *Lightyear* is ([according to the director](https://twitter.com/TheRegister_M/status/1518066994150469632)) the in-universe film that inspired the *Buzz Lightyear of Star Command* cartoon and the Buzz toy that we see in *Toy Story*. As such, it's not immediately apparent where it falls within into the canon timeline, but many of the jokes are dependent on having seen the first two films in the series.

Comment: Actually, from what I understand, the movie Lightyear is meant to be about an actual person named Lightyear that the Tim Allen Buzz is named after, hence why Chris Evans is voicing the character; they're technically 2 different people: the original man and the toy based off of the man.

Comment: @Gothamite - Buzz Lightyear (the toy) is supposedly based on Buzz Lightyear the cartoon.

Comment: What I think is there's the actual guy, then the cartoon that brought in the more exaggerated elements, and then the toy

Comment: @Gothamite - Having Buzz be a real person in-universe (on whom the cartoons and toys are based) would be a total inversion of the earlier films, moving them hundreds of years into the future and opening up lots of additional questions such as *"Why doesn't Andy's mom have a hovercar?"*

Comment: Not necessarily. Look at it this way: the original Lightyear could very easily take place somewhere in from the 60s to the 90s, for arguments sake, let's say 1975. That would leave roughly 20 years for both a cartoon show and toy to be created based off of this person.

Comment: @Gothamite - And then the world of Toy Story regressed technologically from the 2500s (say), back to the 1990s, leaving the only sign of this vast technical progress (laser weaponry, anti-grav, interstellar spaceflight, shield technology) being a crappy cartoon and plastic toy?

Comment: If you want, we can move the discussion to chat, I have many more opinions regarding this. Not trying to disrespect yours, but message me on chat and I'll send a reply

Comment: Its not that far fetched if take the Pixar Theory into account. By the time of Toy Story 1, Syndrome technology has been around for at least 20 years.

Comment: but @Gothamite24 is correct, the info coming out seems to indicate that the new film is about Buzz Lightyear, the real person (in-universe obvs.). The leading theory is that the toy and cartoon were hyper-fictionalized events. Or going back to the Syndrome tech stuff, we are in 2020 and the US has a "Space Force", maybe in their world it came much much sooner, and it being a military op it explains why civilians don't have it.

Comment: @Skooba - *Lightyear* is an in-universe film that exists within the Toy Story universe. We also learn [from the director](https://twitter.com/TheRegister_M/status/1518066994150469632) of *Lightyear* that *Buzz Lightyear of Star Command* exists in-universe and inspired the Buzz toy that Andy gets at the start of *Toy Story*.